Cover drainage which is oval shaped

Waste pipe from laundry sticking out on the wall and water goes to drainage pipe which is oval shape. I am afraid that stone might entered inside the pipe so I checked online the oval grate or dome shaped cover to cover both pipe but couldn't find on the market. Is any cover available in market to cover it?

it looks like the plumber didn't finish,

The big question is why is the water being pushed out to an outside drain that may or may not be connected to anything? It looks like most of the laundry water is overshooting the drain anyways. You will need some way to divert the water down into the drain in addition to a grate.
